# C2 CompilerThread in java

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I run jstack on a java process (oracle jdk1.7_072) and found these lines

```
"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1a8415d000 nid=0x7d72 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1a8415a000 nid=0x7d71 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

I know that C2 is a bytecode compiler. I have three questions:

1. Why there are exact 2 compiler threads? Can it be more or less? If so, when? Does the compilation run in parallel?
2. What does `nid` parameter mean? The first one `nid=0x7d72` looks similar to java version, is it coincidence or not?
3. Why condition address is absolute zero?

Comment: The `nid` is the process id of the thread in hexidecimal. You should be able to find it under /proc in decimal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. The number of compiler threads is determined automatically basing on JVM ergonomics. It may vary depending on number of available CPUs. The exact formula can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/218483967e52/src/share/vm/runtime/advancedThresholdPolicy.cpp#l43). The number of compiler threads can be manually overridden with `-XX:CICompilerCount=N` JVM option.
2. `nid` (Native ID) is a unique ID of a thread given by OS. On Linux it is a number returned by [gettid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html). In your case TID = 0x7d72 = 32114.
3. `[0x0000000000000000]` here is not related to `waiting on condition`. What is printed in brackets is a stack pointer of the last known Java stack frame aligned to a page size. Since compiler thread is not a real Java thread, it does not have last Java SP, hence zero is printed.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, Andrei. I thought the question would sink here.

Comment: If `nid` is number returned by `gettid()` what is `tid` in the question?

Comment: @Steephen `tid` is the address of `Thread` structure - the internal representation of a thread inside JVM.